# How to retrieve value from Map<ArrayList<String>, Object>

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap, set, expandablelistview

I want to know how can I retrieve values from `Map<ArrayList<String>, Object>` Where the String and object are stored as Array [] for user define length.

Here is an Example:

```
                             int counter=0, n=0;

                              if (dataSnapshot.exists()){

                                for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                                    loca[counter]= new ArrayList<>();

                                    itemListProduct[n]= new ItemListProduct();
                                    itemListProduct[n]= ds.getValue(ItemListProduct.class);

                                    loca[counter].add(testHeaderlist.get(counter));

                                    System.out.println(ds.child("item_NAME").getValue(String.class));

                                    objectMap.put(loca[counter],itemListProduct[n]);

                                    counter++;
                                }
```

Here the `testHeaderlist` is an `ArrayList<String>` where there are some string stored.
I wanted to store data in the below Image manner:

[image]

So now my question is how can I retrieve the Key as well as the Object from "dataList". As from the code which I have shared at the TOP "n" number of list, and the object are stored in the dataList.

The thing is that I want to retrieve to use it in ExpandableListView. `loca` as header and `itemListproduct` as my value Object. Where the both are stored at `objectMap`.

Can anyone please solve it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It is permitted but rather atypical to have an `ArrayList` as a key to a map.  To get the `Object` you need to do the following:

```
Object val = map.get(arrayList)
```

Here, `arrayList` **must** contain the exact same strings in the same order as the `ArrayList` key which refers to the desired object.

Example

```
Map<List<String>, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
List<String> key = List.of("abc", "efg");

map.put(key, 20);
Integer v = map.get(List.of("efg","abc")); // different key so
                                           // object not found
System.out.println(v); // prints null

v = map.get(List.of("abc", "efg"));
System.out.println(v); // prints 20
```

You can get all the Keys of a map by doing

```
Set<List<String>> set = map.keySet();
```

You also need to readup on [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html#HashMap--) and [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html) to understand how they work.  The following will keep replacing the object for the key of `list[0]`

```
dataList.put(list[0], object[0]);
dataList.put(list[0], object[1]);
dataList.put(list[0], object[2]);
dataList.put(list[0], object[3]);
```

When the above is done, `list[0]` will only refer to `object[3]`

Comment: Okay. Show now if I want to get the `size()` for `list` of `Object` under `list[0]`, how will I do that.?? from `objectMap`

Comment: You can't because you used the entire List as the key and not the individual items in the list.

Comment: Like how many data are stored in `list[0]`. If I want the size of list[0]

Comment: Try this  `list[0].size();`  Presumes List[0] is an ArrayList or some List implementation.

Comment: thank you, bro, it really helps me out in solving my issue